# mysql login with hashed password

Tags: mysql, password-encryption

I would like to connect to a mysql database e.g. via MySQL Workbench or simply the commandline using mysql utilities like mysql itself or even mysqldump.

When doing so, I would like to avoid plain text password to use.

For my backup process, I have created a my.cnf file to use, but even there the password for the backup user is plain text.

I am not a specialist on this issue that's why I ask.

In my simple world, I would like to hash the password with MD5 or SHA or SSHA or any other and use this hash "{SHA}......" on the commandline or even in the my.cnf.

All tests I have made this way brought up a "wrong password" message.

Is this simple worlds idea possible and if, what do I have to do to avoid storing plain text password somewhere.

To make things more clear. I have found several threads which deal on how to store hashed password in MySQL databases (from a developer point of view). This is not the info I am looking for.

Regards
Karl-Heinz

Comment: That makes no sense to me. When you could connect from a client app with the hashed password to the server the hashed password is the password. It makes no difference in security if someone gets the ~real~ password or the hashed password when he can connect with both to the server.

Comment: As far as I can see MySql stores hashes in the user table and compares a *hash* of what you entered with the hash in that table, so if you pass it a hash it creates a hash of a hash and compares it with the hash in the user table

Comment: Hello Ralf, yes - you are right - obviously wrong thought - close discussion.